# Adding Google font in emails

Tags: css, email, google-font-api

I want to include Google fonts in my newsletter emails.

This is the code I have:

```
$html="
<html>
<style>
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Simonetta);
</style>
<body>
  <p style='font-family:Simonetta'>Hello There</p>
</body>
</html>";

$message->setBody($html, "text/html");
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

But it's not working, it's not displaying the correct font that has been used actually. This is a very simple question & very frustrating, I'm not able to get the solution.

Can anybody please help into it?

I'm using Swift Mailer in case someone needs.

Comment: It won't work in all clients. Which one are you testing in?

Comment: Emails are very tricky, have you read this article? http://blog.campaignmaster.co.uk/2013/01/10/email-101-email-safe-fonts/

Comment: I'm testing for Gmail, Inbox both Android & Web versions.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few clients that accept webfonts (Apple mail, iOS, Android native mail, Thunderbird and Apple versions of Outlook) Your best bet is to use the "old faithful" fonts (eg Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, etc) to ensure cross client support. [Here](http://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/) is a good article from MailChimp on typography in email.